# Transparentar fondo JPanel y visualizar elementos

Tags: java, jpanel

Inserto una **imagen de fondo** en un `JPanel` pero desaparecen algunos elementos de la interfaz. Los siguientes elementos del Java Swing no aparecen:

1. label_titulo
2. label_usuario
3. label_password
4. button_acceder

**¿Se puede hacer la imagen transparente o que los elementos no estén opacados (setOpaque(false)), aún poniéndolo a esos elementos
    no me funciona.**

**¿Por qué algunos elementos tienen un rectángulos encapsuándolos de color gris?**

**Código:**

```
public class InicioSesion extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    private Image imagenFondo;
    private URL fondo;

    public InicioSesion(){
        initComponents();

        try{
            fondo = this.getClass().getResource("fondo.jpg");
            imagenFondo = ImageIO.read(fondo);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.print("Imagen no cargada.");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(imagenFondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

Al cargar **"RUN"** el archivo `.java` me aparece de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Originalmente el **diseño** es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el contrario de usar el `paint` del `JFrame` es al contenedor de todos los componentes de tu diseño al que debes sobre-escribirle el método `paint`, algo mas o menos así:

```
contentPane=new JPanel() {
  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(imagenFondo,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    super.paint(g);
  }
};
contentPane.setOpaque(false);
```

Observa que primero se *renderiza* la imagen del fondo y después es que se llama a `super.paint()`, por ultimo y necesario el `JPanel` debe tener "transparencia" con `setOpaque(false);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]